# check_output doesn't works in python 3.6 while subprocess works fine

Tags: python, subprocess, centos7

i am trying to get the output of a command in my python program by using "check_output" method. but i'm getting this error:

```
   out = check_output(command5 , shell=True)
```

File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_rht-ccp --results-arf arf.xml /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-centos7-ds.xml' returned non-zero exit status 2.

this is the part of my program that is related:

```
command4 = "oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_rht-ccp --results-arf arf.xml /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-centos7-ds.xml"
out = check_output(command4 , shell=True)
```

I am sure that the command is alright because I get the results when I write:

```
subprocess.call(command5,shell=True)
```

I am using python 3.6, and work in centos 7.

any idea why the `check_output` can not get the result?

Comment: Because the command exited with a nonzero exit status, which indicates it failed. `check_call` and `check_output` raise `CalledProcessError` if that happens.

Comment: Thank you @DanielPryden , but why "nonzero exit status" happens? how can i fix it?

Comment: @afsane: that's up to that command to tell you. Look at the stderr output it produces, if any, and read the command documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is *entirely normal*, because the command you ran produced a non-zero exit code. It means that the command you ran is signalling that something may be wrong.

See the [`subprocess.check_output()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError.

and

> This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> run(..., check=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
> ```

where the `check=True` flag tells `run()` to raise an exception when `return_value` is not `0`:

> If check is true, and the process exits with a non-zero exit code, a `CalledProcessError` exception will be raised.

The other function you used, [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), does not set `check=True`:

> Run the command described by `args`. Wait for command to complete, then return the `returncode` attribute.
>
> This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> run(...).returncode
> ```

So either *don't* use `check_output()`, or catch the exception thrown, or fix the command you are running. That `call()` worked is no indication that the *process* actually produced a successful result.

For example, you could use `subprocess.run()` directly:

```
proc = subprocess.run(
    command5, shell=True, text=True
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
if proc.returncode:
    print(f'Issue reported, exit code {proc.returncode}, stderr:')
    print(proc.stderr)
else:
    print(proc.stdout)
```

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters , First I should use "check_output" i need the results in my program, when I use "call()" it also have 2 warning, Do you think, it could be the problem?

Comment: could you please tell me exactly how can I "fix the command"?

Comment: @afsane: I don't know, I am not familiar with the command. I don't know what the exit code is or what that would mean.

Comment: Ok, Thanks anyway.

Comment: @afsane: the [manpage I found](https://linux.die.net/man/8/oscap) states: *oscap returns 0 if all rules pass. If there is an error during evaluation, the return code is 1. If there is at least one rule with either fail or unknown result, oscap-scan finishes with return code 2.* So look at the specific exit code given. Perhaps use `subversion.run()` and do not set `check=True`.

Comment: how can i not set "check=True"?

Comment: @afsane: by using `subprocess.run()` directly and not use `subprocess.check_output()`.

Comment: yeah i am sorry you said that before but i need the results, because i want to pass them to server through socket. may be I should change the command.

Comment: @afsane: `subprocess.run()` gives you access to the results. That's what the code in my answer shows: `proc = subprocess.run(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE, ...)`, then `proc.stdout`.